# ETag support in Spring for versioned entity

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, http-headers

I am planning to support ETag for my RESTfull Spring application. Most of the resources I expose are versioned in DB.

I am aware of ShallowEtagHeaderFilter, which is not exactly, what I need, since it only saves bandwidth.

Is there a production ready solution for Spring MVC that associates ETag header with exposed entity version?

Comment: I found a good article http://www.infoq.com/articles/etags , which is simmilar to what I need, but still needs some work to be done on.

Comment: Hi mavarazy have you seen https://github.com/patrickvankann/spring-conditional-response ?

Comment: No I have not, thanks for the link

Answer (score 9, accepted):

spring-data-rest supports this out-of-the-box, see [the conditional request part of the reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#conditional.etag).

You can also use Spring Framework 4.2.0+ which supports conditional requests for `ResponseEntity` types returned by Controller methods - [see reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-caching).

Something like:

```
@RequestMapping("/book/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Book> showBook(@PathVariable Long id) {

    Book book = findBook(id);
    String version = book.getVersion();

    return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .cacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(30, TimeUnit.DAYS))
                .eTag(version) // lastModified is also available
                .body(book);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ServletWebRequest.checkNotModified` call to check for custom eTags which in your case would be the version number. Again, this would work only if the changes to your content guarantees a change in version number.

More details [here](http://www.codelooru.com/2015/06/etags-and-browser-cache.html).